# $\phi^{n}$ quantum scalar field theories where $n$ is not an integer

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, interactions, locality

Consider a quantum scalar field theory with interaction terms of the form $\phi^{n}$, where $n$ is not an integer.

Where are some examples of widely-studied quantum field theories which involve such interaction terms?

Comment: I suspect you won't find any theories which are `physical'. Typically $n$ is integer because you consider a truncation of a true potential $V(\phi)$ up to some order $n$ using a Taylor expansion; any $\phi^n$ theory is not really a physical theory either but rather an approximation. You will also have some serious branch-cut problems. You should get some cool dispersion relations though!

Comment: Ok, I suppose it does not make sense to consider theories where $n$ is not an integer, because the motivation for the integer-$n$ interaction terms stems from expansion of an arbitrary potential $V(\phi)$. So, let me modify my question to ask if any such studies of non-integer-$n$ interaction terms have been done at all. :)

Comment: As far as I understand it is generally very problematic to quantize theories with Lagrangians/equations of motion which are not polynomials.

Comment: @Blazej Indeed; this is due to the fact that is in general very complicated to understand the quantization procedure in infinite-dimensional systems (essentially due to the fact that the Lebesgue measure does not exist). In addition, it is already sufficiently difficult to understand QFTs with standard polynomial interactions ;-P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A perturbation theory in which is the difference of the $\phi^n$ exponent from 2 is taken as the perturbation parameter has been proposed by Bender, Milton, Moshe, Pinsky, and Simmons in their [article](http://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.37.1472): Novel perturbative scheme in quantum field theory.

This method is called the $\delta$- expansion.

Please see the following [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9607416v1) where the basics of the method is explained in section 2.

The basic construction of the method is based on the following Taylor decomposition of the interaction term:

$$(\phi^2)^{1+\delta} = \phi^2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\delta^n}{n!}\phi^2 (\mathrm{log}(\phi^2))^n $$

One can observe that when $\delta = 0$, the interaction term is quadratic and the theory is free, while when $\delta = 1$, the theory becomes the usual $\phi^4$
theory. In the delta expansion analysis, the effective quantum potential is computed order by order around the free theory corresponding to $\delta = 0$. The obtained theory
is perturbative in $\delta$ but nonperturbative in the coupling constant and the mass.

Each order computation involves a logarithmic interaction term. This term is treated as a limit of a derivative of of a power

$$ \mathrm{log}(x) = \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{d}{dk}x^k$$

Thus the computations are performed for a polynomial theory $(\phi^2)^k$ but only the leading terms in k for $k \rightarrow 0$ need to be computed. For such a theory, the vertices of the Feynman diagrams will be of $2k$ lines. 
Also, it is possible to perform variational calculations order by order in $\delta$.

This expansion gave excellent results for problems in quantum mechanics and solvable models in 1+1 dimensions.

The $\delta$ expansion was used to argue the triviality of $\phi^4$ theory, but did not provide a final proof. Some work was performed at its adaptation to theories with fermions (linear $\delta$ expansion), gauge theory and models in statistical physics.